# Convert array of Objects into single array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

```
0:
   EmpCode: "xxxx"
   EmpName: "tttt"
   EmpRole: "ccc"
   EmailId: "ffff"
   HeadQuarter: "zzz"
   Division :"yyy"
```

My actual data is the one above i am doing a Object.keys(aboveSet) to get the keys as below given array

```
 0: "EmpCode"
    1: "EmpName"
    2: "EmpRole"
    3: "Email Id"
    4: "Head Quarter"
    5: "Division"
    length: 5
```

I am taking doing a Object.key() function to retrieve the keys. How can i convert this array of objects into a single array so my output will look like

```
0:
  EmpCode
  EmpName
  EmpRole
  EmailId
  Head Quarter
  Division
```

Comment: And what about `Object.values()`?

Comment: i dont think it is object, object don't  have length ..

Comment: Please share the data which you have.

Comment: Also please take the time to review how to create a [mcve]

Comment: data not look like proper json/object.. @midhun Update raw data,.. why u adding `console.log` data

Comment: Do you want all unique keys within the array of object

Comment: yes @ShubhamKhatri within an array

Answer (score 1):

The object from your original question:

```js
const fields = {
  0: "EmpCode",
  1: "EmpName",
  2: "EmpRole",
  3: "Email Id",
  4: "Head Quarter",
  5: "Division",
}

const fieldArray = Object.values(fields);
console.log(fieldArray);
```

The object from your edit:

```js
const fields = {
   EmpCode: "xxxx",
   EmpName: "tttt",
   EmpRole: "ccc",
   EmailId: "ffff",
   HeadQuarter: "zzz",
   Division :"yyy",
};

const fieldArray = Object.keys(fields);
console.log(fieldArray);
```

And if for some reason you want those in an array at index 0 (it's hard to tell from your question):

```js
const fields = {
   EmpCode: "xxxx",
   EmpName: "tttt",
   EmpRole: "ccc",
   EmailId: "ffff",
   HeadQuarter: "zzz",
   Division :"yyy",
};

const fieldArray = [Object.keys(fields)];
console.log(fieldArray);
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an array of object and you want to get all unique keys within the object, you can get all keys from each object using `Object.keys` and add it to a set

```js
const data = [{
   EmpCode: "xxxx",
   EmailId: "ffff",
   HeadQuarter: "zzz",
   Division :"yyy",
}, {
   EmpCode: "xxxx",
   EmpName: "tttt",
   EmpRole: "ccc",
   EmailId: "ffff",
},{
   EmpCode: "xxxx",
   EmpName: "tttt",
   EmpRole: "ccc",
   EmailId: "ffff",
   HeadQuarter: "zzz",
   Division :"yyy"
}]
const res = new Set([].concat(...data.map(obj => Object.keys(obj))));
const uniqueKeys = [...res];
console.log(uniqueKeys);
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to put into values of object key? This solution put under every key the key string value:

```
let retValue = {};
yourarray.forEach(item=>{retValue[item]=item});
console.log([retValue]);
```